# How to get a circular view in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing an application for Pico VR headset using Unity. The SDK has a prefab containing two camera.

I have added a quad and a script to change its texture at runtime.

Since the quad is rectangular and display is circular, my texture is unable to fill the screen. If quad is too close to camera, the corners cannot fit the display. If its so far that corners are able to fit inside the headset's display, I am able to see the background at the edges.

The display of HMD looks like a circle (may be spherical - because I have observed the texture that I apply on to the quad looks zoomed in when I run the app on the device). I want to add such object and configure my cameras so that they can view the entire texture of that object and nothing else.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a `Mask ` on the View. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html

Comment: Do you want both cameras to render the exact same portion of the texture? Try using a canvas and putting a [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) on it with your texture on it.